# Cross-browser strong/em insertion using execCommand

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, contenteditable, execcommand

Using *contentEditable* feature and the *execCommand*, one can edit/format the content of certain parts of the page like what is used in all WYSIWYG web-editor. However, there are numerous browsers inconsistencies with the implementation of such feature, which have lead such web-editors to handle them manually.

In my case, IE uses *strong* and *em* elements for the *Bold* and *Italic* commands, which is exactly what I want as I am after the semantic *strong* and *em*, and not the visual-style ones of *b*, *i*, and/or styled *span*. However, other browsers uses those visual-style elements, and don't provide a way to set a *strong* or *em* elements.

**Is there is a way to make it possible to use *strong* and *em* in all the browsers?**
I don't mind adding new commands to handle such thing as long as it achieve an approximate results to the IE ones. Also, it would be **nice** to be able to apply them to intersecting inline/block elements without breaking the browsers (or at least breaking them in an equal manner). Yes, I can use some of the other editors, but I am interested in this feature only. I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: I'm working on a solution for this and will post here when it's ready.

Comment: Cool Tim. I cannot wait to see how you will tackle it. Thanks man.

Comment: My work on this stopped a while ago. I let the scope creep and it all got away from me. I'll get back to it one day.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you mean because I just ran into the same problem. By searching really hard here is something I think helps (a link in StackOverflow):

[Using contentEditable in Firefox: 'bold' renders correctly, but html code is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963172/using-contenteditable-in-firefox-bold-renders-correctly-but-html-code-is-inc)

To see it here, it says, adding the following line before execCommand('bold'):

```
document.execCommand('StyleWithCSS', false, false);
```

I tried and it fixed it, inserting a  in Firefox 13.0.1 (before this, FF inserted "font-weight:bold"). I'm quite excited now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding but you can set em and strong to whatever you want using CSS.

```
strong{ font-weight:bold }
```

Comment: Yes, you are misunderstanding: the question is to do with `document.execCommand()`, which is a method generally used in WYSIWYG editors to change some aspect of the content the user has selected, such as boldness.

Comment: By putting a descriptive question, I was hoping that I make it clear to others. Unfortunately, I failed :)