# Rich text editor, bold text using the strong tag

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, execcommand

I'm working on a very very simple rich text editor. I've read about using designMode = 'On' applied to an iframe, and then I use this to create bold text:

```
nameOfiframe.document.execCommand('bold',false,null);
```

Even though it's works, execCommand() uses `b` tags instead of `strong` to make bold text. I took a look at some advanced rich text editor, all of them used `strong` instead of the `b` tag.

Is there a simple way for me to fix this? Or are execCommand() not good to use at all?

Thanks!

Comment: execCommand() works differently in different browsers: http://help.dottoro.com/ljcvtcaw.php

Comment: FF creates the `B` tag, and `execCommand()` is exactly what's for, to create custom RTE.

Comment: @roXon If you are sure of that, maybe you could make them aware of this by submitting a comment on that page.

Comment: Duplicate question...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235024/cross-browser-strong-em-insertion-using-execcommand?rq=1  ATC's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11771432/888177) seems to offer a possible solution.

Comment: @Stefan, no, I said wrong, now tested in Chrome, it created the `B` tag same as FF, while IE (8,9) creates the `<strong>`. Any way they stated that creates the `<span>` element, which is not the case any more.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `document.execCommand()` behaviour varies between browsers. As @1UnitedPower's answer mentions, `document.execCommand()` is intended for for presentational rather than semantic effect.

Two possible options are:

1. Write your own code to do the bold styling. Unfortunately it is non-trivial to do this properly. You could look at how major WYSIWYG editors such as CKEditor and TinyMCE do it.
2. Run some code to convert `<b>` elements into `<strong>` elements after calling `document.execCommand()`. This would seem the easier option. You will need some way to preserve the selection while doing the conversion, if that's important to you.

Answer (score 0):

`execCommand` does not accept a html-tag-name as its first parameter, but a MIDAS-command.
See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Midas for a list of available commands.

This behaviour is wished, because it targets what a wysiwyg-editor aims for. WYSIWYG is not meant for semantic, but for stylistic purposes. You cannot determine the semantic behind a bold text.

However have a look at `insertHtml` and `styleWithCSS` commands.